# display errors when the username doesn't fit pattern

Tags: angularjs, regex, html, symfony

I'm using symfony and I want to display errors when the username doesn't fit pattern, how can I do that?

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr':{'pattern': '[a-zA-Z]*'} }) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Assert to your property in the entity class.

Check out this for Asserts : http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

And this one for regex : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html

Comment: my problem is to display a specific error  message customized with my own css

Comment: here you go : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#message

Comment: please the pattern works fine my problem is display o =r  override error message